# Problemas SMTP de Yahoo usando PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, hosting, ssl

estoy tratando de configurar el envio de un correo usando PHPMailer y el servidor de Yahoo para hacerlo, lo intenté también usando la de Gmail y Outlook, pero me sigue arrojando el error. Subi una pagina de prueba para poder solventar este problema: http://clinicasbv.tonohost.com/ pero me sigue arrojando el siguiente error de SMTP:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Al final de la linea. El codigo PHP que uso me funciona en local pero no en el

> Hosting byethost, tonohost o 000webhost

Adjunto el codigo PHP

```
// Configuracion servidor
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
                $mail->Port = 587;       
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Timeout = 600;
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
                $mail->Username = '*****@yahoo.com'; 
                $mail->Password = '********';
                $mail->setFrom('******@yahoo.com', 'Clinica mayo');
                $mail->addAddress('*******@gmail.com', 'Joe Davidson');     
                //$mail->addAddress('*******@gmail.com', 'Prueba seria');     

                //$mail->addAttachment('./../../admin/user.jpg');

                // Contenido


                $mail->Subject = 'Activa tu cuenta';
                //$body = file_get_contents(TEMPLATES_L . 'correo/correo_registro.php');
               // $mail->msgHTML($body);
                $mail->Body    = 'Es una prueba <b>in bold!</b>';
                //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
                $mail->isHTML(true);

                // Enviando mensaje

                    $mail->send();
                    echo 'Message has been sent';

            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo "Hubo un error en el envio del token, registrese nuevamente: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
            }
```

Comment: Lograste solucionarlo? Tengo el mismo problema

Comment: Pues si, no estoy seguro como hice exactamente, pero lo que hice en aquel tiempo fue explorar las opciones de cuenta de correo, completar mas la informacion de tu cuenta y permitir que aplicaciones pocas seguras puedan interactuar con el correo. Esa es la parte mas importante, permitir que el correo se pueda usar en app pocas seguras para que sirva en localhost o en un hosting free como byethost. Suerte!